# Python permission error err no 13 permission denied

Tags: python

Trying to run this code, and I keep randomly getting a permission error 13. It's happening randomly as I scrape through a .csv, which makes me think the file is not closing fast enough. I've worked around it by adding a time.sleep(.0000001), but it makes it all run SO SLOW.

```
import csv
import time

OriginalFilePath = 'c:/Users/jason/Desktop/FCC_Stuff/'
OriginalFile = 'bdc_29_Fiber-to-the-Premises_fixed_broadband_063022'
OriginalExt = '.csv'
CompleteOriginalFile = OriginalFilePath + OriginalFile + OriginalExt

with open(CompleteOriginalFile) as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    TheList = []
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
            HeaderRow = row
            line_count += 1
            print("")
            print(HeaderRow)
        else:
            Brand = (row[2])
            if Brand in TheList:
                TheOutputFile = OriginalFilePath + Brand + OriginalExt
                with open(TheOutputFile, 'a', newline='') as csvoutput:
                    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, delimiter=',')
                    csv_writer.writerow(row)
                csvoutput.close()

            if Brand not in TheList:
                print(Brand)
                TheList.append(Brand)
                TheOutputFile2 = OriginalFilePath + Brand + OriginalExt
                with open(TheOutputFile2, 'a', newline='') as csvoutput2:
                    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvoutput2, delimiter=',')
                    csv_writer.writerow(HeaderRow)
                    csv_writer.writerow(row)
                csvoutput2.close()
        line_count += 1
csv_file.close()

print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')
print("")

print("done")
```

Any other ideas how to get this to run a little faster?

This is where I added in the time.sleep:

```
import csv
import time

OriginalFilePath = 'c:/Users/jason/Desktop/FCC_Stuff/'
OriginalFile = 'bdc_29_Fiber-to-the-Premises_fixed_broadband_063022'
OriginalExt = '.csv'
CompleteOriginalFile = OriginalFilePath + OriginalFile + OriginalExt

with open(CompleteOriginalFile) as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    line_count = 0
    TheList = []
    for row in csv_reader:
        if line_count == 0:
            print(f'Column names are {", ".join(row)}')
            HeaderRow = row
            line_count += 1
            print("")
            print(HeaderRow)
        else:
            Brand = (row[2])
            if Brand in TheList:
                TheOutputFile = OriginalFilePath + Brand + OriginalExt
                with open(TheOutputFile, 'a', newline='') as csvoutput:
                    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, delimiter=',')
                    csv_writer.writerow(row)
                csvoutput.close()
                time.sleep(.0000001)

            if Brand not in TheList:
                print(Brand)
                TheList.append(Brand)
                TheOutputFile2 = OriginalFilePath + Brand + OriginalExt
                with open(TheOutputFile2, 'a', newline='') as csvoutput2:
                    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvoutput2, delimiter=',')
                    csv_writer.writerow(HeaderRow)
                    csv_writer.writerow(row)
                csvoutput2.close()
                time.sleep(.0000001)
        line_count += 1
csv_file.close()

print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')
print("")

print("done")
```

Comment: `permission denied` usually occurs when the file is locked (often in a windows process).

Comment: a millionth of a second wait is likely not your issue (compared to opening files, writing output, and closing files...

Comment: also, if you use a context manager (`with`) then `csv_file.close()` is automatically done for you.

Comment: @topsail That is another thing I found weird too, it doesn't seem to matter what I change that sleep to, it's just slow as slow can be. The millionth of a second, was my 7th try at making it faster. I just kept adding another 0, obviously didn't help.

Comment: @D.L I didn't know (with) did that. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: How many rows are in `CompleteOriginalFile`? and how many distinct "Brands" are there?  Approximate is fine

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. For debugging help, you need to narrow down the problem into a [mre], as well as post the [full error message with traceback](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341). This here is probably more code than necessary to reproduce the issue, so paring it down should help identify the problem. As well, you don't need to post the full code twice; you can just comment out the `sleep` lines. For more tips, check out [ask]. You can [edit] your post.

Comment: BTW, `if Brand not in TheList` is the opposite of `if Brand in TheList`, so just use `else`.

Comment: @JonSG
2.5 Million rows in the CompleteOriginalFile
<50 Brands

Comment: I might be missing something here but; why are you even closing the output files? Just open them once in the beginning of the code and close them after the `for` loop. :s

Comment: @wjandrea
That's actually the way I had it, originally. I was just randomly trying some different things to beat it into submission. Either way, it still hates me. At least it will be done before 5.

Comment: @doneforaiur
Well, I don't know what all the brands are. I could grab those in an initial pass through the file, and then open all the files. Just seemed inefficient. I've also thought about just dumping the entire thing into an array, and writing it all at once too. I was just hoping it was something dumb and easy to fix.

Comment: @done That's what I thought too, but the `Brand` can change each loop. On the other hand if you mean not using a context manager, then the file handling would get annoying.

Comment: Also, AFAIK the data is written to the file once you `close` it. That's why you can't see data while it is being written to the file but the writing task is done. So you should increase `time.sleep()`, not decrease, right? If there's less than 50 brands, you can `unique` the list of the column and I think it'll be pretty fast too. Outside of this question's scope but `pandas` would make such a difference in this example. Just group by the `brand` column and you're done.

Comment: @wjandrea, annoying BUT efficient. :^)

Comment: Actually, you can open files as you iterate over the main `csv`. Create a list of file handlers, if the file handler for that specific `brand` is present in the list then find and use that file handler. If not, open a new file handler and append it to the list. This approach doesn't requiere you to scan the whole document first, however it might be an easy fix you were searching for.

Comment: Expanding on what @doneforaiur is suggesting, instead of having `TheList`, you could have `brand_files = {}` where `key = brand` and `value = (file_handle,  csv_writer)`  If brand isn't in brand_files, open the new file and point a csv_writer at it, storing both in the dictionary, otherwise, just write the line using the already open csv_writer. 
  After `csv_reader` is exhausted, loop over brand_files and close all of the open filehandles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've made a few changes here to use `Pathlib.Path` and use `csv.DictWriter`, with the assumption that the input file has a column header of "Brand".  Change as needed.

This solution is using a dictionary to track the filehandle and csv.DictWriter for each brand. I did test it and confirmed it works, but I was using a much smaller hand-crafted data set with only 4 brands, so its possible you may run into some limits I didn't.
Perhaps it can be combined with the contextlib.ExitStack() suggestion from JonSG; I have not investigated that yet.

```py
import csv
from pathlib import Path

OriginalFilePath = Path('c:/Users/jason/Desktop/FCC_Stuff/')
OriginalFile = Path('bdc_29_Fiber-to-the-Premises_fixed_broadband_063022.csv')
OriginalExt = OriginalFile.suffix

# Combine the Paths
CompleteOriginalFile = OriginalFilePath / OriginalFile

# Declare this before the with block so that we don't get a NameError
# later if we never actually process any rows.
brand_files = {}

with open(CompleteOriginalFile) as csv_file:
    line_count = 0
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    if "Brand" not in csv_reader.fieldnames:
        raise ValueError('Expected column named "Brand" missing from input file.')
    
    
    for row in csv_reader:
        line_count += 1
        if (brand := row["Brand"]) not in brand_files:
            print(brand)
            brand_files[brand] = {}
            output_file = OriginalFilePath / Path(brand + OriginalExt)
            brand_files[brand]["file"] = open(output_file, 'a', newline='')
            brand_files[brand]["writer"] = csv.DictWriter(brand_files[brand]["file"], fieldnames = csv_reader.fieldnames) 
            brand_files[brand]["writer"].writeheader()
            # print(f"Created {brand_files[brand]}")
        brand_files[brand]["writer"].writerow(row)
    
# Close each brand's output file. Do this outside of the with block
# so that we still clean up if an exception occurs while reading input.
for brand in brand_files.values():
    brand["file"].close()


print(f'Processed {line_count} lines.')
print("")

print("done")
```

Comment: This was beautiful. It worked like a charm. 2.5 Million rows in 26 seconds. There was one small hiccup. Someone named their company "Lightwave Communications| llc"
Note the pipe
Beyond that, it worked perfectly.
Thanks!

Comment: @vbj4 Glad to hear it. I realized one change I should make to the code, which I will do when I get back to my PC.  The loop that closes all of the brand files should be moved outside of the `with` block to ensure that we clean up and close any opened files if an exception is raised while reading the input file.

Answer (score 2):

I might look at using an [`ExitStack()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.ExitStack) to help manage opening and closing the various files. There are limits to how many files you can have open but hopefully 50 is fine.

Note that this is untested, but I think it might work for you.

```py
import contextlib
import csv

OriginalFilePath = 'c:/Users/jason/Desktop/FCC_Stuff/'
OriginalFile = 'bdc_29_Fiber-to-the-Premises_fixed_broadband_063022'
OriginalExt = '.csv'
CompleteOriginalFile = OriginalFilePath + OriginalFile + OriginalExt

writers = {}
with contextlib.ExitStack() as stack:
    file_in = stack.enter_context(open(CompleteOriginalFile, "r"))
    csv_reader = csv.reader(file_in)
    header = next(csv_reader)
    for row_number, row in enumerate(csv_reader, start=1):
        print(f"processing row: {row_number}", end="\r", flush=True)
        Brand = row[2]
        if Brand not in writers:
            file_out_path = OriginalFilePath + Brand + OriginalExt
            file_out = stack.enter_context(open(file_out_path, "w", newline=""))
            writer = csv.writer(file_out, delimiter=',')
            writer.writerow(header)
            writers[Brand] = writer
        writers[Brand].writerow(row)
    print()
print("done")
```

Comment: I tried this as well, and it does work. Thank you for your assistance.